# <Google> Must set the rootViewController property of GADBannerView before calling loadRequest:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, admob

I use Google AdMob SDK in my iPhone app,
I did set the rootViewController property, delegate property

```
self.adBannerView.rootViewController = basedViewController;
self.adBannerView.delegate = basedViewController;
[self.adBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

but keep getting this message while running the app:

```
<Google> Must set the rootViewController property of GADBannerView before calling loadRequest:
```

I manage 3 GADBannerView at the same time, do you know the status of GADBannerView (does it have rootViewController set or not) while debugging the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the basedViewController is not created yet. Step 1) Create the viewcontroler Step 2) Assign

Answer (score 1):

Use your code at end of View Did Load on your viewcontroller.m